# Java loop inside a loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops

What I want to do here is a loop inside a loop and I want to increment the inner loop by the value of the counter in the outer loop.

The error I get is "Not a statement", pointing at "b + s ) inside the inner for-loop

```
for( int s =1; s < 100; s++){
    if( 100 % s == 0){
        for( int b = 0; b < 100; b + s ){
            locker[b] = locker[b] * (-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Is my goal achievable at all?

Comment: What is `b + s` meant to do?

Comment: Try `b += s` instead of `b + s`

Comment: Do you mean `b += s`?

Comment: b is the counter for the inner loop and the value is supposed to increment by s from the outer-loop

Comment: Ahh b+= s works perfectly.

Thanks azurefrog & AntonH

Comment: @azurefrog I posted a CW answer for posterity.

Comment: Also, to save a small operation, you can change `locker[b] = locker[b] * (-1);` to `locker[b] = -locker[b];`

Comment: @LaughDonor I didn't know about that, thanks for the little tip.

Comment: @LaughDonor The second way is a bit clearer to me, but it won't save any operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
for( int b = 0; b < 100; b + s ){
```

Into:

```
for( int b = 0; b < 100; b += s ){
```

This operator, also known as the *addition assignment* operator, will add `s` to `b`'s original value and store it back into `b`.

Information is from [Azure's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923994/java-loop-inside-a-loop/22924031#comment34991993_22923994).

Answer (score 0):

**Where is `b + s` result stored?**

What would be the point to let the third part's result of `for` loop, "volatilized"? Maybe for side effects only..but would be too hidden.. not recommended.

Without a storing variable (pleonasm :)), your loop would end up with the same outcome at each step.

Thus, `b += s` would make more sense since `b` would store each new value, then usable in your loop content.